# Quartz.Net Schedule Job

Tags: c#, scheduling, jobs, quartz.net

I am new to this and our project already uses this scheduling library. We wrote a new job (a class) and would like to schedule this to run maybe once a day. How do we do this? Do we insert any records in the database (in the `qrtz_` tables) or do we have to schedule it some other way? Also are the records for these jobs inserted automatically in the database tables or are they done manually?

Their documentation is not very clear. I am looking into it right now but if someone can point me in the right direction it will be greatly helpful.

Documentation - http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html

Comment: What language are you using? Are there any libraries available on the project/product website that might help you here? Have you tried creating a record in a `qrtz_` table, and if so what was the effect? Are there any docs as to what those tables do?

Comment: it's in C#. We have their library that we imported in the proj. There are multiple tables for this library and it has certain columns that I am not sure what values go in those. And no I cannot find any documentation on these tables.

Comment: OK, there is an example in those docs that runs every 40 seconds. Are there any other methods like `WithIntervalInSeconds` for hours or days? Or can you use the same with `24 * 60 * 60` seconds (i.e. a day's worth)?